# Where is the complete documentation of the SparkR GroupedData object?

Tags: sparkr

Many things can be done with the groupBy function in SparkR.

Here's an example from the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/groupBy.html):

# Compute the average for all numeric columns grouped by department.

`avg(groupBy(df, "department"))`

But I'm very curious about the "GroupedData" object generated by the groupBy function, which is mentioned in the groupBy documentation and also has it's [own page](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/GroupedData.html).

According to that documentation, the following code will generate a GroupedData object:

`groupBy(df, "department")`

Unfortunately the [page for the "GroupedData" object](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/GroupedData.html) appears incomplete or I don't know how to find the object documentation for it. The [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/GroupedData.html) says it's "A Java object reference to the backing Scala GroupedData"- I tried searching the Scala documentation on spark.apache.org and found nothing there.

I'm looking for a list of the "GroupedData" class members and methods similar to documentation I have found for other programming languages. Depending on what I find I may have some novel ways to use this object for analysis I am doing in SparkR. Also, the answer to this question will help me with many similar questions I have about finding documentation of other SparkR objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alwys refer to the [PySpark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.html) if you think SparkR documentation is not adequate, at least I do that :), there are many common APIs

Comment: this is actually cool, I had checked SparkR docs and searched in Scala docs without finding what I was looking for, but unlike SparkR, the pyspark docs do indeed have a list of methods, and I can test and see if they work in SparkR